# Django pre-fill a form drop down box based on url request

Tags: python, django

I would like to pre-fill a drop down box based on a URL request from a URL tag.  I'm trying to get it where the site is a list of books, and when you're on a book page, if you want to take some notes on that book, then you would hit the "take notes" button, and it would take you to a note form page where the drop down box at the top for the name of the book would be pre-filled from the title of the book page that you just came from.

My url on the "book/detail.hmtl" page looks like this:

```
{% url 'books:take_notes' book.id %}
```

view.py - then for the take notes page I tried to prefill the NoteForm() like this:

```
def take_notes(request, book_id):
  mybook = Book.objects.get(pk=boo_id)
  form = NoteForm(initial={'book':mybook.title})
```

urls.py -

```
url(r'^take_notes/(?P<book_id>\d+)/$', views=take_notes, name='take_notes'),
```

The NoteForm() has 3 fields

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note 
        fields = ('book', 'title', 'note',)
        widgets = {
            'note': forms.Textarea,
        }
```

When I use initial for "title" it will prepopulate, but it won't for 'book' because it is a drop down box.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `book_id` instead of `book` in the view as

```
 form = NoteForm(initial={'book_id':book_id})
```

Comment: Your's and Daniel Roseman's advise was spot on.  This is a ForeignKey field, so I had to look it up by id and not by a string.  The syntax that i used and worked was: form = NoteForm(initial={'book':book_id})

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to prepopulate the select box by passing the title, which is presumably what is displaying in the control. But you should pass the underlying value, which in the case of a ForeignKey is the id of the related object.

Comment: Thank you for you and Rohan's help.  I put a comment above.  It is working now!